# React Native Gesture Handler shows: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I have setup a react-native 0.61 project which runs without any error but I'm getting this whenever I swipe. I am using **react-native-gesture-handler: 1.3.0**.

My

> TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'rectEvt[mappingKey]'). Please see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7VQM.jpg) for detail

I am using the following code:

```
const circleRadius = 30;
class Circle extends Component {
  _touchX = new Animated.Value(windowWidth / 2 - circleRadius);
  _onPanGestureEvent = Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {x: this._touchX}}, { useNativeDriver: true }]);
  render() {
    return (
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={this._onPanGestureEvent}>
        <Animated.View style={{
          height: 150,
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
          <Animated.View
            style={[{
                backgroundColor: '#42a5f5', borderRadius: circleRadius, height: circleRadius * 2, width: circleRadius * 2,
              }, {
                transform: [{translateX: Animated.add(this._touchX, new Animated.Value(-circleRadius))}]
              }]}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the arguments to **Animated.event** in a wrong way:

```
_onPanGestureEvent = Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {x: this._touchX}}, { useNativeDriver: true }]);
```

The Animated.event should have the following structure:

```
_onPanGestureEvent=Animated.event(
   [{nativeEvent: {x: this._touchX}}],
   { useNativeDriver: true }
   {listener},          // Optional async listener
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue appears after install `react-native-draw` package with a previous react-native-gesture-handler installed.

The issue was `ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeGestureHandler.Gesture.Pan')`

I realized that the file `Canvas.tsx` in `node_modules/@benjeau/react-native-draw/src` had a warning in the import:

```
import {
  Gesture,
  GestureDetector,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Then I thought it could be due to the package version, I had version 1.10.3 when uninstalling the package and installing it again updated to version 2.13.4 and the problem was solved.

```
npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler --save

npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
```